# Duplicating/Copying Project Settings(Preferences) within a Visual Studio Solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I am building a "Solution" consisting of many small "Projects" within VS-2015.
To ensure consistency, I would like to set Project preferences such as additional include directories, additional libraries and platforms from one location or copy from one project to the next.
Could you please point me to a document that describes this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all projects are based on MsBuild, you can create a single targets file which sets the properties you want to sync across your projects. You can then import this targets file in every one of your project files.

To add a targets file you'll need to edit the `csproj` file directly (Unload project, edit project file in VS or through a 3rd party editor).

There are also some options like `Directory.build.props` and `Directory.build.targets` files, in Visual Studio 2017 these are automatically imported during your build and that gives you the advantage of not having to edit the project files. This may require MsBuild 15, which ships with Visual Studio 2017.

Some Visual Studio UI will be able to show the current value of certain properties, but editing them in the UI will pull these values back into to project files. This is an unfortunate behaviour of Visual Studio.

For all options to import targets files see:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2017

Comment: You can call those files you import just about anything. You can import an *.xml file, a *.props file, anything really, as long as it is an XML MSBuild file. Generally I like to call my file's *.props, for properties.

Comment: Right, but there are some standard names that will be auto-imported and as such won't require changes to the project files.

Comment: oh wow, I read the web-page you linked. Automatic import. Woah, that's new, and pretty cool too!